# Postgres trigger not working as expected

Tags: java, postgresql, triggers, plpgsql

Postgres 9.4 Triggers behaving abnormally,

I need guidelines on how to ensure the triggers are working and possible reasons it's not working

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION recieptfunction()
  RETURNS trigger AS
$$
BEGIN 
IF ( NEW.dlr_mask=31 ) THEN 
INSERT INTO test1(
            rec_id, sender, receiver, udhdata, msgdata, "time", smsc_id,
            service, account, id, sms_type, mclass, mwi, coding, compress,
            validity, "deferred", dlr_mask, dlr_url, pid, alt_dcs, rpi, charset,
            boxc_id, binfo, meta_data, foreign_id, client_track_id, msg_cost,
            stid, gstid, smsid, gctid, sendreport, mno, requestresptime,
            dsm, identifier, userid, receiptcallback, replycallback, replyemail,
            delemail, sentemail, nextdayearliestsendtime, replyemailflag,
            replymsg, replytime, momt, "isUnicode",status)
    VALUES (NEW.sql_id, NEW.sender, NEW.receiver, NEW.udhdata, NEW.msgdata, NEW."time", NEW.smsc_id,
            NEW.service, NEW.account, NEW.id, NEW.sms_type, NEW.mclass, NEW.mwi, NEW.coding, NEW.compress,
            NEW.validity, NEW."deferred", NEW.dlr_mask, NEW.dlr_url, NEW.pid, NEW.alt_dcs, NEW.rpi, NEW.charset,
            NEW.boxc_id, NEW.binfo, NEW.meta_data, NEW.foreign_id, NEW.client_track_id, NEW.msg_cost,
            NEW.stid, NEW.gstid, NEW.smsid, NEW.gctid, NEW.sendreport, NEW.mno, NEW.requestresptime,
            NEW.dsm, NEW.identifier, NEW.userid, NEW.receiptcallback, NEW.replycallback, NEW.replyemail,
            NEW.delemail, NEW.sentemail, NEW.nextdayearliestsendtime, NEW.replyemailflag,
            NEW.replymsg, NEW.replytime, NEW.momt, NEW."isUnicode",NEW.dlr_mask);


ELSIF(NEW.dlr_mask=1) THEN 


        UPDATE  test1 set dlr_mask_del_success=NEW.dlr_mask, "time_del_success"=NEW."time",status=NEW.dlr_mask,showfinalstatus=true where service=NEW.service;


        ELSIF( NEW.dlr_mask=8 ) THEN 

  UPDATE  test1 set dlr_mask_smsc_sub=NEW.dlr_mask, "time_smsc_sub"=NEW."time",status=NEW.dlr_mask,showfinalstatus=false where service=NEW.service;



ELSIF( NEW.dlr_mask=16 ) THEN 

  UPDATE  test1 set dlr_mask_smsc_rej=NEW.dlr_mask, "time_smsc_rej"=NEW."time",status=NEW.dlr_mask,showfinalstatus=true where service=NEW.service;




 ELSIF( NEW.dlr_mask=4 ) THEN 

  UPDATE  test1 set dlr_mask_msg_buf=NEW.dlr_mask, "time_msg_buf"=NEW."time",status=NEW.dlr_mask,showfinalstatus=false where service=NEW.service;


ELSIF( NEW.dlr_mask=2 ) THEN  

 UPDATE  test1 set dlr_mask_del_failure=NEW.dlr_mask, "time_del_failure"=NEW."time",status=NEW.dlr_mask,showfinalstatus=true where service=NEW.service;





ELSIF( NEW.dlr_mask IS NULL ) THEN 
INSERT INTO sql_reply_reciept_sms(
            sql_id, sender, receiver, udhdata, msgdata, "time", smsc_id,
            service, account, id, sms_type, mclass, mwi, coding, compress,
            validity, "deferred", dlr_mask, dlr_url, pid, alt_dcs, rpi, charset,
            boxc_id, binfo, meta_data, foreign_id, client_track_id, msg_cost,
            stid, gstid, smsid, gctid, sendreport, mno, requestresptime,
            dsm, identifier, userid, receiptcallback, replycallback, replyemail,
            delemail, sentemail, nextdayearliestsendtime, replyemailflag,
            replymsg, replytime, momt, "isUnicode")
    VALUES (NEW.sql_id, NEW.sender, NEW.receiver, NEW.udhdata, NEW.msgdata, NEW."time", NEW.smsc_id,
            NEW.service, NEW.account, NEW.id, NEW.sms_type, NEW.mclass, NEW.mwi, NEW.coding, NEW.compress,
            NEW.validity, NEW."deferred", NEW.dlr_mask, NEW.dlr_url, NEW.pid, NEW.alt_dcs, NEW.rpi, NEW.charset,
            NEW.boxc_id, NEW.binfo, NEW.meta_data, NEW.foreign_id, NEW.client_track_id, NEW.msg_cost,
            NEW.stid, NEW.gstid, NEW.smsid, NEW.gctid, NEW.sendreport, NEW.mno, NEW.requestresptime,
            NEW.dsm, NEW.identifier, NEW.userid, NEW.receiptcallback, NEW.replycallback, NEW.replyemail,
            NEW.delemail, NEW.sentemail, NEW.nextdayearliestsendtime, NEW.replyemailflag,
            NEW.replymsg, NEW.replytime, NEW.momt, NEW."isUnicode");




ELSE  RAISE EXCEPTION 'Date out of range.  Fix the measurement_insert_trigger() function!';
END IF;    


RETURN NEW;
END;
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql ;
```

This is the Trigger

```
CREATE TRIGGER afterinsert
    AFTER INSERT ON test
    FOR EACH ROW
        EXECUTE  PROCEDURE recieptfunction()
```

The Trigger behaved abnormally it had entered almost all data but had left some data uninserted in test1 table, I have checked the logs it has no error during insertions. Does 9.4 version Triggers do behave sometimes abnormally, Do I need to change the version.

Comment: What exactly is the expected behaviour? Just claiming that it's "abnormal" doesn't give much insight on what you are trying to achieve

Comment: "*Does 9.4 version Triggers do behave sometimes abnormally*" - they behave the way you write them. There is no known bug in trigger executions in 9.4 (or any later version)

Comment: Expected behaviour is to insert every data that comes on to test table to be inserted or update , but it has not inserted some datas into test1 but datas are there on test table

Comment: Maybe it ran into one of the `update` cases but didn't update any row, because there is no row in `test1` with a corresponding key.